# Erro com Data angular.js mysql PDO

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

Boa tarde,

Estou com dificuldades em realizar UPDATE com data porém a data sempre fica 0000-00-00.

Estou usando angular.js e mysql PDO.
Pesquisei aqui no fórum alguns problemas semelhantes mas até agora sem sucesso.
Como sou iniciante, gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Data de Emissão do Token</label>
    <input type="text" id="dt_token" ng-model="dt_token" autocomplete="off"  class="form-control" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#dt_token").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
nextText: 'Próximo',
prevText: 'Anterior',    
beforeShow: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.clsDatePicker').css('z-index', 100000);
        }, 0);
    }
});


var app = angular.module('crudApp', ['datatables']);


app.controller('crudController', function($scope, $http){

$scope.fetchData = function(){
    $http.get('fetch_data.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.namesData = data;
    });
};

$scope.openModal = function(){
    var modal_popup = angular.element('#crudmodal');
    modal_popup.modal('show');
};

$scope.closeModal = function(){
    var modal_popup = angular.element('#crudmodal');
    modal_popup.modal('hide');
};

$scope.addData = function(){
    $scope.modalTitle = 'Add Data';
    $scope.submit_button = 'Insert';
    $scope.openModal();
};

$scope.submitForm = function(){     
    $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"insert.php",
        data:{'nome':$scope.nome, 'token':$scope.token, 'dt_token':$scope.dt_token, 'action':$scope.submit_button, 'id':$scope.hidden_id}
    }).success(function(data){
        if(data.error != '')
        {
            $scope.success = false;
            $scope.error = true;
            $scope.errorMessage = data.error;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.error = false;                   
            $scope.successMessage = data.message;
            $scope.form_data = {};
            console.log($scope.dt_token);
            console.log($scope.token);
            $scope.closeModal();
            $scope.fetchData(); 
        }
    });
};

$scope.fetchSingleData = function(id){
    $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"insert.php",
        data:{'id':id, 'action':'fetch_single_data'}
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.nome = data.nome;
        $scope.token = data.token;
        $scope.dt_token = data.dt_token; //data.dt_token;
        $scope.hidden_id = id;
        $scope.modalTitle = 'Edit Data';
        $scope.submit_button = 'Edit';
        $scope.openModal();
    });
};

$scope.deleteData = function(id){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?"))
    {
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"insert.php",
            data:{'id':id, 'action':'Delete'}
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.error = false;
            $scope.successMessage = data.message;
            $scope.fetchData();
        }); 
    }
};

});
```

SQL

```
<?php

//insert.php

include('database_connection.php');

$form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$error = '';
$message = '';
$validation_error = '';
$nome = '';
$token = '';
$dt_token = '';

function debug_to_console( $data ) {
    $output = $data;
    if ( is_array( $output ) )
    $output = implode( ',', $output);

    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' ); 
</script>";
}

if($form_data->action == 'fetch_single_data')
{
    $query = "SELECT id, nome, token, dt_token FROM funcionario WHERE 
id='".$form_data->id."'";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output['nome'] = $row['nome'];
        $output['token'] = $row['token'];
        $output['dt_token'] = $row['dt_token'];

    }
}
elseif($form_data->action == "Delete")
{
    $query = "
    DELETE FROM funcionario WHERE id='".$form_data->id."'
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if($statement->execute())
    {
        $output['message'] = 'Data Deleted';
    }
}
else
{
    if(empty($form_data->nome))
    {
        $error[] = 'Nome do Funcionario e necessario';
    }
    else
    {
        $nome = $form_data->nome;
    }

    if(empty($form_data->token))
    {
        $error[] = 'Informacao do Token e necessario';
    }
    else
    {
        $token = $form_data->token;
    }

    if(empty($error))
    {
        if($form_data->action == 'Insert')
        {
            $data = array(
                ':nome'     =>  $nome,
                ':token'        =>  $token,
                ':dt_token'     =>  $dt_token
            );
             $query = "
            INSERT INTO funcionario 
                (nome, token, dt_token) VALUES 
                (:nome, :token, :dt_token)
            ";
            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            if($statement->execute($data))
            {
                $message = 'Data Inserted';
            }
        }
        if($form_data->action == 'Edit')
        {

            $data = array(
                ':nome' =>  $nome,
                ':token'    =>  $token,             
                ':dt_token' =>  $dt_token,
                ':id'           =>  $form_data->id
            );


            $query = "
            UPDATE funcionario 
            SET nome = :nome, token = :token, dt_token = :dt_token WHERE id 
= :id
        ";


            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            if($statement->execute($data))
            {
                $message = 'Data Edited';

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $validation_error = implode(", ", $error);
    }

    $output = array(
        'error'     =>  $validation_error,
        'message'   =>  $message
    );

}


echo json_encode($output);






?>
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.